# Regex fomatting and design for a query

Tags: php, regex

I'm having a some trouble formatting my regular expression for my PHP code using preg_match().
I have a simple string usually looking like this:

"q?=%23asdf".

I want my regular expression to only pass true if the string begins with "q?=%23" and there is a character at the end of the 3. So far one of the problems I have had is that the ? is being pulled up by the regex so doing something like

^q?=23 doesn't work. I am also having problems with contiguous searching in Regex expressions (because I can't figure out how to search after the 3).

So for clarification: "q?=%23asd" should **PASS** and "q?=%23" should **FAIL**

I'm no good with Regex so sorry if this seems like a beginner question and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the requirement is: Start with `q?=%23`, followed by at least one `[a-z]`, the pattern could look like:

```
$pattern = '/^q\?=%23[a-z]+/i';
```

Used `i (PCRE_CASELESS)` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). Also see [example at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/hJ9bO0/1).

Comment: @and0rsk Great it helps :) Note, that you can discard the `+` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) after `[a-z]`, if it's only for matching. Was more for the regex101 example. see [eval.in](https://eval.in/189315)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a lookahead to check whether the character following `3` is an alphabet or not,

```
^q\?=%23(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

Add `.` instead of `[A-Za-z]` only if you want to check for any character following `3`,

```
^q\?=%23(?=.)
```

Code would be,

```
$theregex = '~^q\?=%23(?=[a-z])~i';
if (preg_match($theregex, $yourstring)) {
    // Yes! It matches!
    } 
else { // nah, no luck...
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "q?=%23asdf";
var_dump(figureOut($string));
function figureOut($string){
    if(strpos($string, 'q?=%23') == 0){
        if(strlen($string) > 6){
            return true;
        }else{ return false;}
    }
}
```